# Modify file with open handle

Tags: windows, powershell, window-handles

I'm running into a strange issue with a text file that has an open handle in another process.  If I open the text file in notepad, I'm able to modify and save data to the file.  However, I cannot delete the file, it gives the standard warning from Windows about the file being open in another application.

What I'm attempting to do is modify (not delete) that same file with PowerShell rather than notepad.

So generally I would just use something like:

```
$File = "F:\Event Data\Exchange.txt"
(Get-Content $File) -replace ' - TextToBeRemoved ', ' - ' | Set-Content $File
```

This is throwing an error in PowerShell:

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'F:\Event Data\Exchange.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

So if I can modify and save content through Notepad, what in PowerShell would be the equivalent? I'd rather not hunt down and kill the open process as this would cause other/larger issues.

I've also tried this with the same resulting error:

```
(Get-Content $File) | foreach-object {$_ -replace ' - TextToBeRemoved ', ' - '} | Set-Content $File
```

It may not matter but I'm using -replace rather than .replace due to case inconsistencies, so I'd like to stick with that or something also case neutral.

Thanks.

Comment: What you have should have worked. Do you see this with new file you created and closed with sample data? Wonder if you have another PowerShell session or something like that open for instance. Is F a network drive with someone else working on it?

Comment: F is not a share, no one else is using this file or drive.  There is only the one open handle I can see in Resource Monitor.  It's not a new file I created, it's an existing file I'm modifying, but yes, after I modify and close notepad, the changes are retained.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) can show you what the two processes are doing differently.  (That may or may not help solve the problem, but it should at least clarify it.)  It's probably down to the access rights Powershell is requesting when it opens the file.

Comment: What is your powershell version then? Maybe this is a pipe issue. What happens when you do. `$data = Get-Content $File; $data -replace ' - TextToBeRemoved ', ' - ' | Set-Content $File`. Again the code you have should have worked. Perhaps it is a 2.0 issue or something

Comment: Yea, I thought of this as well, I even upgraded to WMF 3.0 before posting, this gives me the same result though.

Comment: For what it's worth, these appear to be the last Create Operations reported by Proc Mon for different attempts, the top (Notepad) works, but bottom (PowerShell) returns error:

Comment: 4:17:22.0443118 PM NOTEPAD.EXE 8636 CreateFile F:\Events\Exchange.txt SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Disallow Exclusive, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Opened

Comment: 4:15:24.6448015 PM powershell.exe 8960 CreateFile F:\Events\Exchange.txt SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened

Comment: That operation is succeeding.  The one that fails must be elsewhere, either that or Powershell is just lying to you.  (Is it possible that the Set-Content is conflicting with the Get-Content, not the other process?  Does it work if there isn't another process with an open handle?)

Comment: It's definitely the other process, I've killed it manually and the operation works just fine.  But to answer your question, it definitely does not succeed otherwise, despite what Proc Mon is indicating.  I think Proc Mon is just not picking up the error that PowerShell is generating since PS is not letting it get far enough, all operations show as SUCCESS in Proc Mon.  The whole thing is kinda bizarre but my guess it has something to do with the open handle allowing writes, but PowerShell is just detecting an open handle and not even trying.

Comment: Does the Process Monitor entry (for Powershell) look any different when the other process isn't running?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [`System.IO.FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can specify whatever access you want on the file. You can also specify the file mode. Or if that doesn't work you can P/Invoke Win32 CreateFile/ReadFile/WriteFile/CloseFile APIs.

But as Harry pointed out in the comments you need to figure out what operation is failing and process monitor is a good way to do it. I would filter on the powershell process and on a failure return code.

If that doesn't reveal anything, then PS is failing the operation for some other reason. In that case you'll just have to replicate the arguments to open the file that Notepad uses the best you can and hope it works.

Ultimately most all user mode file opens and creates in Windows funnel through CreateFile. If you go the P/Invoke route you can exactly duplicate what Notepad does.